# $M\setminus \mathrm{Cut}(L)$ deforms to $L$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a connected complete Riemannian manifold, $p\in M$ and $\mathrm{Cu}(p)$ denotes the [cut locus of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_(Riemannian_manifold)). This is a standard result that $M\setminus\mathrm{Cu}(p)$ deforms to $p$.

Now if $L$ is a compact submanifold of $M$ and $\mathrm{C}u(L)$ denotes the cut locus of $L$ then is it true that $M\setminus \mathrm{Cu}(L)$ deforms to $L$. I checked some of the examples and it worked. But I am unable to prove this fact. Any reference or proof will be appreciated.

**Edit**

- We say $q\in \mathrm{Cu}(L)$ if any distance minimal geodesic joining $L$ to $q$ is no longer distance minimal beyond $q$.
- By deformation, I mean to find  $$H:M\setminus \mathrm{Cu}(L)\times [0,1]\to M\setminus \mathrm{Cu}(L)$$ such that $H(x,0)= x,~ H(q,1)\in L$ and $H(q,t)=q$  (if $q\in L$).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the definition of $Cu(L)$ in the post? Thanks.

Comment: You should also define what you mean by "deforms to $L$."

Comment: Your definition of "deform" is what one usually calls [strong deformation retraction/retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)#Deformation_retract_and_strong_deformation_retract).

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean.

Comment: I guess if you take a $\varepsilon$ disk bundle of $N$ and then take the exponential map that is precisely the set $M-\mathrm{Cu}(N)$. Then you can deform this to $N$. Probably this should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming the submanifold has no boundary.  In this case it is true that $M\setminus cut(L)$ deformation retracts to $L$.  I'm not sure what happens if there is boundary.

Let $\nu L$ denote the normal bundle of $L$.  For each $v\in \nu L$, let $t_v\in [0,\infty]$ denote the time where the geodesic $\exp(tv)$ stops minimizing distance to $L$.

We define $U\subseteq \nu L$ by $U = \{tv \in \nu L: \|v\| = 1\text{ and } t<t_v\}$.

Then, according to [this paper](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pmsc/098/02-03/0179-0186), $\exp|_{U}:U\rightarrow M\setminus Cut(L)$ is a diffeomorphism.  Just to make notation a bit nicer, I'll use $\rho$ to denote $\exp|_{U}$.

Now, define $H:M\setminus C(L)\times [0,1]\rightarrow M\setminus C(L)$ by $H(m,t) = \exp((1-t)\rho^{-1}(m))$.

This is a composition of continuous functions, so is continuous.  Further, $H(m,0) = \exp(\rho^{-1}(m)) = m$.  Further, $H(m,1) = \exp(0\cdot \rho^{-1}(m)) \in L$.  Lastly, for any $\ell\in L$, $\rho^{-1}(\ell)$ is in the zero section of $\nu L$, so $\exp((1-t) \rho^{-1}(\ell)) = \ell$, independent of $t$.

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice answer.

Comment: @XYZABC:  I'm glad you like it.  That said, I'd hold of on accepting it - maybe someone will treat the case where $L$ is a manifold with boundary?